# Finding formulas in a degree sequence of a grid graph

Tags: graph-theory

**Given:**

$G_{m,n}$ is a graph with $mn$ vertices; it is a grid of $n$ rows with length $m$ (or vice versa); one has edges between consecutive vertices in each row and column

$m$ and $n$ are both greater than one

the degree sequence is $4^a 3^b 2^c$

$c=4$ since $m$ and $n$ are both greater than one

$a+b+c=mn$

**Question:**

Find formulas for $a$ and $b$ in terms of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Please typeset your formulas (see help).

Comment: I've taken the liberty of LaTeX-ifying your question, but if you post again, see, for example, [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Draw a sample graph. You'll see that there are 4 corner vertices of degree 2, as you noted. Then, along the boundary there will be $2(n-2)+2(m-2)$ vertices of degree 3. Finally, a similar count will give the number of interior vertices of degree 4. You should be able to fill in this last part.